# Connected to wifi, but no internet access

Tags: wi-fi, huawei, internet, dns, connectify

first question here. I was using wifi normally on my phone. Then I turned it off and after some time turned it back again. Since then I can not access the internet. It's showing `Connected(no internet access)`.

I tried to set the IP static. It did not work for DNS `192.168.200.1`. No matter what IP I set with this DNS it does not work. Then used the `8.8.8.8` as DNS, now it's connected. But it is really slow, and the connection does not seem stable. Every time I have to reload google.com several times just to get the page.

The problem is specific to this device only. Other devices connected to the same network are perfect.

I tried

- Restarting the router
- Resetting network settings
- Clearing network cache from maintenance mode
- Rebooting the device with and without airplane mode

My phone is Huawei Y9 2018 with Android 9.

Can someone suggest me what should I do? Is this a router issue? Or is this my device problem?

I'm new in this area. So my knowledge is not so deep and you might have to explain things a bit more in detail for me to grasp the concept.

Comment: Based on your description this a router problem and/or a problem of your Internet connection, not a problem with your Android phone. If the router would be configured correctly you would not have to change anything in your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going wrong here.

*Why* would you want to select `192.168.200.1` as DNS? It looks like a private IPv4 address, not a DNS address. Doing so, I believe you will fail to connect to internet.

In my experience DNS addresses have looked like `8.8.8.8` - like you mentioned, and `8.8.4.4`.

You can try to use custom IP addresses like `192.168.200.1` keeping the DNS `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4` only.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your router address is `192.168.200.1`.

There can be several reasons:

1. You can try to force your router to support only high-speed connections. It depends on the router and you will need to check your manual.
2. It is possible that your phone changed a frequency from 2.4GHz to 5GHz recently or vice-a-versa. You may check that both the router and the phone support it and try to connect to a different frequency. Usually there are two different WiFi points in this case. So it is hardly the case.
3. Your upstream connection can be unstable. It is possible that your phone reacts to unstable connection more notably than other devices however I don't think it is the most probable case. I guess this is the hardest case to check.
4. You phone is malfunctioning. You can test it by trying different routers somewhere or by bringing one to your home. If it is the case then it may be hardware issue, bad system update, or possibly other software issue. I would try to reinstall browser, uninstall all VPN apps, check battery usage, uninstall apps that eat too much, and a factory reset as a last resort.
5. If your phone works nicely with other routers it may be a compatibility issue. Given that your phone worked nicely it can be caused by system update of your phone or system update of your router. Depending of what the issue is you may try a factory reset of your router, a factory reset of your phone or buying a new router.
6. Certainly I missed something and there are much more reasons